# How to define matching column in InverseProperty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

In my MVC application, I have an entity relation between Student and Lookup tables with StatusID-LookupKey and GenderID-LookupKey pairs inestead of (StatusID-ID and GenderID-ID pairs). However, not being able to define the LookupKey column as the matching parameter with the StatusID and GenderID, I have to use ID column of Lookup table. How can I use InverseProperty and match the related columns to the LookupKey column? Thanks in advance.

Here are the Lookup table and the entities below:

**Lookup Table:**

```
ID | LookupType | LookupKey | LookupValue |
1  | Status     | 0         | Passive     | 
2  | Gender     | 1         | Male        | 
3  | Status     | 1         | Active      | 
4  | Gender     | 2         | Female      | 
5  | Status     | 2         | Cancelled   |
```

**Lookup Entity:**

```
public class Lookup
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }        

    public string LookupType { get; set; }

    public int LookupKey { get; set; }

    public string LookupValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    //This works when using PK (ID) as matching column. 
    public ICollection<Student> StatusLookupStudents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> TermLookupStudents { get; set; }
}
```

**Student Entity:**

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Status
    public int StatusID { get; set; } 

    //Foreign key for Gender
    public int GenderID { get; set; }


    //This works when using PK (ID) as matching column. But I want to use LookupKey column for matching
    [ForeignKey("StatusID")]
    [InverseProperty("StatusLookupStudents")]
    public virtual Lookup StatusLookup { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TermID")]
    [InverseProperty("TermLookupStudents")]
    public virtual Lookup TermLookup { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to subclass the lookups using `LookupType` as discriminator.

Comment: Could you please give an example by using the code above?

Comment: Shouldnt the `[InverseProperty]` be on the navigational properties in the LookUp table

Comment: Could you pls give an example on the code above?

Comment: @GertArnold Are you there?

Comment: @gerdi Are you there?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @gerdi Thanks, but before asking the question I had already look at that page and applied these steps. But, it does not meet my requirements. I need to give a relation reference to "LookupKey" column instead of ID column. How to do this?