# How to setup two foreign keys to the same parent column (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I have the following class models

Position:

```
public enum PosType
{
    ICC, FP
}

public class Position
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PosType? PosType { get; set; }
}
```

Staff:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }

    //FK to Position
    public int PositionId { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
```

Member:

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }

    //FK to Staff model which stores the ICC Staff Type value
    public int? StaffId { get; set; }

    //FK to Staff model which stores the FP Staff Type value
    public int? FPNumber { get; set; }

    //Navigation property 
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
```

On the Member model the `StaffId` property is a foreign key to the `Staff` model which is a pretty straight forward approach. The issue I'm having is how to handle the `FPnumber` property since I would like it to be a foreign key to the `Staff` model as well. My overall goal is have the `Member.StaffId` property store ICC staff type and the `Member.FPNumber` property store FP staff type. I tried adding the `ForeignKey`  attribute to the `FPNumber` property, but it did not work since the `StaffId`got removed from the Member table. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping a foreign key with a custom column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148662/mapping-a-foreign-key-with-a-custom-column-name)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
public class Member
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string MemberName { get; set; }

//FK to Staff model which stores the ICC Staff Type value
[ForeignKey("Staff")]
public int? StaffId { get; set; }

//FK to Staff model which stores the FP Staff Type value
[ForeignKey("FPStaff")]
public int? FPNumber { get; set; }

//Navigation property 
public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }  //Use a better descriptive Name than Staff

public virtual Staff FPStaff{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend renaming the "Staff" member to be more precise.